# How to know the size of assembly lines of code between two c++ break points?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, assembly

I'm building a c++ project under eclipse, and to perform cache optimization I need to estimate if some hot spot of the code can fit in cache. I put two break points and triggered eclipse disassembler, but it looks hard to manually count the code by this way..

Is there is any idea for more practical way?

Comment: You can generate an assembly listing with "gcc -S" and look at the assembly output in a text editor :)

Comment: You first need to profile the code, and do optimization only after.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a sensible method to check whether code fits in cache. E.g. Sandy Bridge (the current Intel x86 architecture) has a 1.5kB micro-ops cache. That doesn't convert 1:1 to 1.5kB of x86 instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Have your compiler emit assembly output.  Be sure to do this for Release builds, as they will often be very different than Debug builds.  You can then analyze the output manually, and see how much memory will be needed for your code.

You've mentioned Eclipse, so I assume you are talking about gcc under Linux, but this is also true for MSVC under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to estimate is to subtract the addresses, and divide by the average instruction size.  On the x86 I'd use 4 bytes (you may choose a different number).